# Validation rule for a composite unique index (non-primary)

Tags: validation, cakephp, composite-key

I am sure I am not the first who has composite unique keys in tables and who wants to validate them. I do not want to invent the bicycle so I ask here first. I have several tables that have 'id' columns as primary keys and two other columns as unique composite keys. It would be nice to have a validation rule to check that the submitted entry is unique and display a validation error if it is not. In Cakephp it could be done by a custom validation rule. I am pretty sure somebody has created such method already.

Ideally it would be a method in app_model.php that could be used by different models.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using that function:

```
function checkUnique($data, $fields) {
    if (!is_array($fields)) {
            $fields = array($fields);
        }
        foreach($fields as $key) {
            $tmp[$key] = $this->data[$this->name][$key];
        }
    if (isset($this->data[$this->name][$this->primaryKey]) && $this->data[$this->name][$this->primaryKey] > 0) {
            $tmp[$this->primaryKey." !="] = $this->data[$this->name][$this->primaryKey];
        }
    //return false;
        return $this->isUnique($tmp, false); 
    }
```

basically the usage is:

```
'field1' => array(
                'checkUnique' => array(
                    'rule' => array('checkUnique', array('field1', 'field2')),
                    'message' => 'This field need to be non-empty and the row need to be unique'
                ),
            ),
'field2' => array(
                'checkUnique' => array(
                    'rule' => array('checkUnique', array('field1', 'field2')),
                    'message' => 'This field need to be non-empty and the row need to be unique'
                ),
            ),
```

So basically this will show the warning under each of the fields saying that it's not unique.

I am using this a lot and it's working properly.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I wanted. The only outpoint is that it produces 2 identical queries when 2 fields are validated.

Answer (score 0):

In the CakePHP/2.x versions released in the last few years, [the `isUnique` rule](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique) optionally accepts several columns:

> You can validate that a set of fields are unique by providing multiple
>   fields and set `$or` to `false`:
>
> ```
> public $validate = array(
>     'email' => array(
>         'rule' => array('isUnique', array('email', 'username'), false),
>         'message' => 'This username & email combination has already been used.'
>     )
> );
> ```

I'm not sure of the exact version when the feature was available but there's [a bug](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/39011cd9d8def8308629991af5f5bda0d01040d1) fixed in core as late as October 2014 filed against 2.3 and 2.4 branches.

Answer (score -1):

You could put it in app model, but my suggestion would just be to add it to the model directly by placing the rule with it's `$validate` property.

Check out the built in [isUnique rule](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html).

Comment: 'isUnique' validates only one field for a single column. I need the validation rule for two columns that compose the composite unique key.

Comment: I see. Sorry. Then yes, if this is something in multiple models, I would built a custom validation rule and put it in app_model.php.