# CakePHP unique compound field validation (not unique each field, but as a whole)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So I need to validate if both fields are the same,  not each field on its own. By that I mean:

```
id (auto increment)  |  field_1  | field_2
------------------------------------------
          1          |    1      |    1
```

if I try to insert  `null,1,1` it will show error. But if I go `null,1,2` it inserts it with no problem.

In conclusion, the whole (field_1, field_2) is what's is unique (also know as compound primary key).

how can I validate this in Model?

**EDIT:** I tried this: [Validation rule for a composite unique index (non-primary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445483/validation-rule-for-a-composite-unique-index-non-primary), but it validates each field on it's own, so if I go `null,1,2` it won't insert, cause `field_1 = 1` already exists in the table

Comment: Write own validation method, here is example : http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/aranworld/2008/01/14/using-equalto-validation-to-compare-two-form-fields Article is quite old but idea is the same.

Comment: I use my "validateUnique" for that, see [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/07/maximum-power-for-your-validation-rules/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this custom validation function on Model.

```
public function compositUniqueKey($data){

if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['field1']) && isset($this->data[$this->alias]['field1']) ){  
    $check = $this->find('first', array(
                                        'conditions' => array(
                                            'field1' => $this->data[$this->alias]['field1'],
                                            'field2' => $this->data[$this->alias]['field2']
                                        )
                                    )
                                );
    if(!empty($check)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[Model::isUnique()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Model.html#3249-3291) is a rule that can be used and is already implemented in the CakePHP core.

> Returns false if any fields passed match any (by default, all if $or =
>   false) of their matching values.

```
isUnique(array('field1', 'field2'), false));
```

Notice the false, if the 2nd arg is not set to false it won't work like you want it because it's using OR instead of AND then.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html it doesn't mention that function receiving parameters at all

Comment: The API documentation does. http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Model.html#3249-3291 Feel free to correct the book, it's open for everyone to make changes.